# it is possible to extend a php function?

Tags: php, mysql, logging

My question is if it's possible to extend a declared function.

I want to extend mysql_function to add mysql query that insert into a table some logs : 'query' - the parameter of mysql_query, date,page...etc

Comment: why the question of extend? why not define a function that uses the function and implements what you want.

Comment: Write a custom function...would be much less painful that touching php core...

Comment: for that purpose yoy'd better create trigger on insert/update/delete

Comment: i have a web site that runs whit simple mysql_query functions. And now i whant to put logs on every querry in the simple solution possible whitout changing all the code. For this web site i have not implemented any personal class.

Comment: You did not accept an answer yet. Can you please clarify what you are looking for in an answer and why the given answers do not satisfy you.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is if it's possible to extend a declared function.

No.

You can extend a class method and call `parent::methodname()` to run the previous code (which is *almost* what you ask for), but for normal functions, there is no way to do this.

There are some esoteric PHP extensions that allow *overriding* functions, but I assume that's not what you need and their use is  rarely practical.

What you probably want to do is create a new function, and call the existing function in it.

Comment: i have a web site that runs whit simple mysql_query functions. And now i whant to put logs on every querry in the simple solution possible whitout changing all the code. For this web site i have not implemented any personal class.

Comment: @user I see. Unless you can use any of the methods offered by Gordon, I'm afraid I don't think you'll get around writing a custom function.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that. Either enable the [MySql Query Logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html) or wrap the code doing the queries into a [Logging Decorator](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) or use an abstraction like [Zend_Db that can take a Profiler](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html) or use a [transparent logging plugin for mysqlnd](http://blog.mayflower.de/archives/578-MySQLnd-Plugins-Writing-a-MySQL-Query-Logger-in-PHP.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that will take your query, log the sql first, runs your query, then return the results.

E.G

```
<?php

function mysql_query_log($sql)
{
    mysql_query('insert into .... values ...');

    $r = mysql_query($sql);
    $results;
    //do the normal thing you do with mysql here
    return $results;

}
```

This is not extending a function though, you can only extend a class

Comment: dont forget to escape your sql when you insert it into the log table.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

You should have created your own API (or use an existing one) to access the DB so when you need logging you can simply enhance your own API function. It also comes very handy if you need some custom error handling function. Refactor the code.

Comment: i have a web site that runs whit simple mysql_query functions. And now i whant to put logs on every querry in the simple solution possible whitout changing all the code. For this web site i have not implemented any personal class.

Comment: you have to encapsulate everything that might be altered later (adding logging, error handling, authentication, whatever...) or you have to later refactor. like now..

Answer (score 0):

Well.. PHP says this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Answer (score 0):

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php

> bool rename_function ( string $original_name , string $new_name )
>
> Renames a orig_name to new_name in the global function table. Useful
>   for temporarily overriding built-in functions.

I believe that if you rename the original to original_mysql_query, then add your replacement function which does your logging and then calls original_mysql_query etc, that you will achieve your goal, assuming that you have the way to inject the rename on every page that will call MySQL_query. Most large sites have common code that is included at the top of every page that could do that for you.

There is also a built in php function called override_function (mentioned by ChrisH). It is not fully documented in the php man page but the user comments below the doc give you the information that you need to use it if you prefer it to the rename_function function. There was a discussion about being limited to one override if you needed to call the original function from the replacement.  Using the rename_function instead of the override function eliminates that potential restriction.